# Present perfect or not?

Tags: grammaticality

I have some sentences that I wanted to ask the experts here.

When emailing people in present tense, do I have to use future tense in order to be grammatically correct?

> "You **need** to call me whenever you **receive** my parcels, because that **is** the only way for me to find out if my parcels **have been received**."

Should this be:

> "You **need** to call me whenever you receive my parcels, because that **will be** the only way for me to find out if my parcels **are** received."

or

> "You **need** to call me whenever you receive my parcels, because that **will be** the only way for me to find out if my parcels **have been received**."

On the sentence below, I'm not sure if I should construct it with present perfect.

> "Sometimes, I **find** that **I've done** something I **shouldn't have done**."

Should it be:

> "Sometimes, I **find** that I **did** something I **shouldn't have done**."

The one below, I actually read it in a book.

> "I'm sorry, you shouldn't have to see that"

Is this some kind of present tense sentence? I think is should be "you shouldn't have seen that", but since I read this in a book, it must be correct.

Please help!

Comment: 1) Your second and third sentences are identical! 2) In your last sentence, *have to see* is not a perfect construction *have to* = *must*. That is *you should not be compelled to see that*.

Answer (score 1):

For your first example, I would prefer your first form of the sentence, although you could also probably say,

> "You need to call me whenever you receive my parcels, because that **is** the only way for me to find out **when** my parcels are received."

For the second example, both sentences are gramatical with subtly different meanings. For the meaning that I am assuming you are intending, you should use your first sentence.

For example #3, "You shouldn't have to see that" is a sympathetic statement, while, "You should not have seen that" is more of a matter-of-fact statement.